# Добавляю количество вкладок в табах и пропадает паралакс, почему?

Tags: jquery, css, вёрстка, parallax

Есть табы в блоке и через пару экранов на фоне едут фендиклюшки(паралакс) все ок, заходят за экран сверху и снизу, но если добавить 5-10 вкладок табов, вроде должно быть все ок и это никак не связано но эти финдиклюшки начинают пропадать раньше чем зайдут за экран, а если добавить еще больше табов то их не будет видно. Как это исправить и с чем это связано?

Между этими экранами еще пара штук и высота у них около 1000px. Можете объяснить что происходит?

Comment: Неплохо было бы увидеть твой _css_ код

Comment: Извините, не удержался - но слово фендиклюшки - крутое :)))

Comment: Использую этот http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/
Вот код: https://jsfiddle.net/cb9m3ng2/2/ там один экран и css к нему. 
Вот эти финдеклюшки 

                    <div class="line2" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
                        <img src="images/box_177x209.svg" alt="" data-stellar-ratio="2">
                    </div>

                    <div class="scales2" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
                        <img src="images/apple_134x137.svg" alt="" data-stellar-ratio="2">
                    </div>

Безз табов все хорошо работает.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь параллаксу **height: 200%**

Пример css кода:

```
.bg {
background: url('bg.jpg') repeat;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 200%;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Или подобрать скорость прокрутки

Пример:

```
function parallax(){
var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
$('.bg').css('top', -(scrolled * 0.2) + 'px');
}
```